# Overlaying (plotting) point data on raster layer

Tags: r, ascii, raster

So I have the following script trying to prepare the data to do modelling on them later on using "biomod2" package. It tries to overlay species (xlm) presence points on environmental layers (bio1, bio7).

```
library(biomod2)
library(raster)

    data <- structure(list(longitude = c(-122.84,-119.418,-78.6569,-78.1834, -89.3985), latitude = c(45.28,36.7783,37.4316,-1.8312, 32.3547)), .Names = c("X_WGS84", 
"Y_WGS84"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
data$xlm<-1

spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = data,
                               proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

myRespName <- 'xlm'
myResp <- as.numeric(data[,myRespName])
myRespXY <- data[,c('X_WGS84','Y_WGS84')]
myExpl = stack( system.file( "external/bioclim/current/bio3.grd", package="biomod2"),
system.file( "external/bioclim/current/bio4.grd", package="biomod2"))
myBiomodData <- BIOMOD_FormatingData(resp.var = myResp,expl.var = myExpl,resp.xy = myRespXY,resp.name = myRespName)
plot(myBiomodData)
```

It works in this case, however, the issue is when I want to replace "bio4.grd" and "bio3.grd" layers in the package with my own data, it doesn't work. I have tried it as follow. First i thought it might be "asci" file format but even by converting them to "grd" still I don't get the points overlayed on layers stacked. It does overlay only one point in Southern USA (around Louisiana, Mississippi) though.

```
library(biomod2)
library(raster) 

data <- structure(list(longitude = c(-122.84,-119.418,-78.6569,-78.1834, -89.3985), latitude = c(45.28,36.7783,37.4316,-1.8312, 32.3547)), .Names = c("X_WGS84", 
"Y_WGS84"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
data$xylella<-1

spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = data,
                               proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

myRespName <- 'xylella'

myResp <- as.numeric(data[,myRespName])

myRespXY <- data[,c('X_WGS84','Y_WGS84')]

bio2<-raster("C:\\Data\\BioClim_V2_MaxEnt\\wc2.0_bio_10m_02.asc")
crs(bio2) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" 
writeRaster(bio2, "C:\\Data\\BioClim_V2_MaxEnt\\bio2", overwrite=TRUE)

bio7<-raster("C:\\Data\\BioClim_V2_MaxEnt\\wc2.0_bio_10m_07.asc")
crs(bio7) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" 
writeRaster(bio7, "C:\\Data\\BioClim_V2_MaxEnt\\bio7", overwrite=TRUE)

myExpl = stack (bio2,bio7)

myBiomodData <- BIOMOD_FormatingData(resp.var = myResp,expl.var = myExpl,resp.xy = myRespXY,resp.name = myRespName)

plot(myBiomodData)
```

Any help highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: please provide a simple reproducible example --- I see way too much to much code doing all kinds of things not related to the problem at hand. Also, just include some of the points as code instead of a file that needs to be downloaded.

Comment: @RobertHijmans Thanks for the comment Robert, I have tried to tidy it up. I hope its better now. Cheers

Comment: It is better but it still refers to files "C:\\Data\\BioClim_V2_MaxEnt\\wc2.0_bio_10m_02.asc" that we do no have. You can do `as.character(bio2)` to create a reproducible version. The writing to "grd" does not affect it but in your scrip these files are not even used either.